# Why do enthalpy changes of combustion and formation not take into account oxygen?

Tags: enthalpy

I've seen many enthalpy changes in my studies and I don't understand why the oxygens on either side of reactions are not calculated (especially if the unreacted oxygens don't balance). For example:

$$\ce{2C(s, graphite) + 3H2(g) + 1/2O2(g) ->  C2H5OH(l)}$$

Comment: It would be much easier to discuss/answer the question if it contained a specific example.

Comment: @airhuff 2C (s, graphite) + 3H2 (g) + 1/2O2 (g) --> C2H5OH (l).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention elements in their most stable polymorph at standard conditions have at standard conditions (298.15 K) a standard enthalpies of formation $\Delta{}_fH^\circ$ of zero ([one reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_formation)).  This is why thermodynamics discerns C(graphite) from C(diamond), and C(fullerene), for example.  Hence on first view *it looks like* zeros in your example (graphite, Hydrogen, Oxygen) got forgotten; but they are not.